# How can I rollback insert statements after commit in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let  me re-explain it.I am oracle newbie, I have tried to search online with no success.Can anyone please tell me how can I create a rollback script after committing  Insert statements in oracle Database?.Note,I have not commited insert statements yet .I simply want backup rollback script in case anything happens after insert and commit statements in production environment.

Comment: You have already committed the transaction, and this the symbol for ending that trans, there is no way to roller back committed stuff unless you  roll back the entire database

Comment: @LONG, I have not commited yet,i simply want  rollback backup script in case anything happen after insert statements

Comment: If they are all inserts, the "rollback" of those would simply be a set a matching deletes - no?

Comment: Do you have **savepoint**? If so you could rollback your work by `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT [name of savepoint]`

Comment: @LONG  I don't have savepoint.Can you please explain with more code?

Comment: @Danny I give you example below see whether it is good for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

```
begin
statement;
   savepoint savepoint1;
   begin
      your insert statement
   exception
       when others then
      rollback to savepoint1;
  end;
      ROLLBACK TO savepoint1;
end;
```

Comment: glad that I could help @Danny

Answer (score 2):

If you have not yet `COMMIT;`ed, then all you need to do is `ROLLBACK;`

If you want greater control, then you can create savepoints throughout the transaction:

```
SAVEPOINT before_inserts;
```

and later on to rollback to the savepoint:

```
ROLLBACK TO before_inserts;
```

If you've had the misfortune to have committed your work only to discover a mistake, you may be able to make use of flashback queries to revert the table and/or database to a previous state.

Comment: Thank you Sentinel